# Condition for a point to be a limit point of some set in general topology

Tags: general-topology

I generated many topological spaces for certain finite sets.
{{}, {1}, {2}, {4}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2,
4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};
{{}, {1}, {4}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3,
4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};
{{}, {1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {2, 3,
4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}.

I noticed a pattern that when {a} isn't an open set, 'a' is a limit point of some subset of X.
I tried to prove it the following way using an example.
{{}, {1}, {2}, {4}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2,
4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
1,2,4 etc can't be limit points because {1}, {2}, {4} are open sets.

If {1,3} is open, {2,3} can't be open because their intersection is {3}(which isn't open).
Any higher open neighborhood of 3 will have to contain {1,3} in it, thus making 3 the limit point of any set containing 1.
This condition seems quite strong. I haven't seen it being mentioned anywhere.
So i want to be sure if my argument is correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Examples are not proofs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true indeed, and here is a simple *argument* (an example does not prove a general observation!) why:

In a finite topological space $(X, \mathcal T)$ every point $x$ has a minimal open neighbourhood $M_x = \{O \in \mathcal T\mid x \in O\}$ (open as a *finite* intersection of open sets).

If $\{x\}$ is not open this means that there is some $y \in M_x$ such that $y \neq x$. Then by definition $x$ is a limit point of any $A$ with $y \in A$ (because if $O$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$, $y \in M_x \subseteq O$ is a witness). In particular $x \in \{y\}'$.

In your example $M_3 = \{1,3\}$ so there any set containing $1$ will do. Minimal neighbourhoods are a nice concept in the study of finite topological spaces; they are a natural base and elicudate the limit point relations between sets very nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of Minimal open neighborhoods. I thought about it in some detail and came to following ideas(finite case): 1) Intersection of MONs is also MON. 2) Any limit point which is an element of a MON is a limit point of that MON. I used these ideas to get intuition about the theorem that a set is closed iff it contains all it's limit point. Can we define a Minimal closed neighborhood similarly?